# Tapkey Token Exchange - better understanding the token exchange request

Tags: access-token, tapkey

Regarding retrieving an access token via tapkey token exchange:

Assuming I have two identity providers registered on Tapkey, which use the same public key:
Now I make the request to: `POST https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token` including in the request body the `client id` and the `provider`.

Is it safe to assume, that I will only retrieve access tokens for the Users of the identity provider, which is defined in `provider` in the request-body?
The right identity provider is selected by `provider` and NOT by the signature of the jwt-token I am sending for exchange, right?

Answer (score 1):

Right, the signature itself is only used for validation.

The provider of the request will be the identity provider in the exchanged token.

But:

- The client must be setup to use this identity provider
- The subject token must be signed with the configured token
- The audience and issuer claim in the subject token must match the configured identity provider.
- ...

It is fine to use the same private key to sign jwt tokens for multiple identity providers. But the audience should be different to disallow an interchange of tokens between different identity providers.

Normally we wouldn't expect the need of multiple identity providers, except the users has to be strictly separated.

Comment: just doublechecking, if I understand your answer correctly:
you said:
"The provider of the request will be the identity provider in the exchanged token."

Does that mean, that the jwt token I send in the request is definetly exchanged only for an access token which is only usable for an IdentityProviderUser of the IdentityProvider specified in the request body?

Comment: Right, otherwise an undesired hijacking of users would be possible.

The client must be configured to be allowed to use the identity provider and the jwt token must be properly signed for this identity provider. This ensures that you can only get an access token for your users and not for foreign ones and vice versa.